# How can I get contains(List<Matcher> itemMatchers) to compile in Java 7?

Tags: java, hamcrest

I am learning Hamcrest 1.3 and I want to come up with an example for each Hamcrest static method in [Matchers](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html). The Javadoc helpfully already has examples for some methods. I tested the following [contains](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#contains%28java.util.List%29) code snippet with Java 8 and it passed:

```
assertThat(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"), 
           contains(Arrays.asList(equalTo("foo"), equalTo("bar"))));
```

However, my team is currently using Java 7 so I wanted to make sure all the examples work in that version. The above code snippet produces the following error in Java 7:

> no suitable method found for assertThat(java.util.List,org.hamcrest.Matcher>>>)
>       method org.junit.Assert.assertThat(T,org.hamcrest.Matcher) is not applicable
>         (actual argument org.hamcrest.Matcher>>> cannot be converted to org.hamcrest.Matcher> by method invocation conversion)
>       method org.junit.Assert.assertThat(java.lang.String,T,org.hamcrest.Matcher) is not applicable
>         (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

I know that Java 8 added new implicit typing features for static methods and I think this is likely related. I have attempted to refactor out parameters and casting them to the expected arguments, but that results in the same error:

```
List<String> actual = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar");
List<Matcher<String>> expected = Arrays.asList(equalTo("foo"), 
                                               equalTo("bar"));
assertThat(actual, contains(expected));
```

What is the proper way to call `static <E> Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends E>> contains(java.util.List<Matcher<? super E>> itemMatchers)` in Java 7?

Comment: From what it looks like the compiler error is unrelated to type inference, and is instead something about the method having the incorrect number of arguments...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Hamcrest Javadoc, the method signature for the `contains()` that you're targeting is:

```
 public static <E> Matcher<Iterable<? extends E>> contains(List<Matcher<? super E>> itemMatchers);
```

The important bit to note in the above signature is the `List<Matcher<? super E>>`. Java 7 cannot infer `List<Matcher<? super E>>` from `List<Matcher<String>>`. The `contains()` is additionally overloaded, so the signature of the method that Java 7 targets is:

```
public static <E> Matcher<Iterable<? extends E>> contains(E... items);
```

And this is the reason you're getting the cryptic compilation error message!

Fortunately, the fix is pretty straightforward:

```
List<String> actual = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar");
List<Matcher<? super String>> expected = Arrays.<Matcher<? super String>>asList(equalTo("foo"), 
                                                                                equalTo("bar"));
assertThat(actual, contains(expected));
```

Comment: Does adding the explicit type parameter `<String>` to the `contains` call also fix the typing? It seems like that would force the compiler to pick the correct variant of `contains`.

Comment: @DaoWen Unfortunately not, the compiler will still select the `contains(E... items)` variant instead of the desired `contains(List<Matcher<? super E>> items)`.

Comment: Using `hasItem` instead of `contains` seems to help avoid the problem while maintaining readability.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the libraries installed to readily test this, but I think this is a subtyping problem.

- `expected` has type `List<Matcher<String>>`
- `contains(expected)` has type `Matcher<Iterable<String>>`
- `actual` has type `List<String>`
- `assertThat` needs a first argument of type `T` and a second of type `Matcher<T>`
- Your `T` is `List<String>`, which means it expects the second argument of type `Matcher<List<String>>`, not `Matcher<Iterable<String>>`.

I'm guessing this should fix it:

```
Iterable<String> actual = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar");
List<Matcher<String>> expected = Arrays.asList(equalTo("foo"), 
                                               equalTo("bar"));
assertThat(actual, contains(expected));
```

Again, I haven't tested this fix—but that seems like it would clear up the type issues.

Comment: This does look closer but sadly does not compile. Muel's solution works. Thank you.